# Can I use c++ with stm32f7?

Tags: stm32f7

I have been looking through the examples provided STM32Cube_FW_F7 downloaded St.com website.

I noticed that all of them are using c, is there a way for me to use c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Question is not correct!*

If you asking: **Can I use C++ for STM32?** Answer: **Yes, All compilers support C++ (GCC, IAR, KEIL)**

If you asking: **Do you have some C++ library for support STM32F7 MCU**? Answer: **No, at the moment public community doesn't have a good solution for you.** You can find libraries for STM32F0 or STM32F4 but not for F7 family.

Also, you can check [ARM mbed](https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.9/introduction/index.html) project, may it will suitable for you.

Comment: What you mean't is I can use C++ as long as I avoid using any standard libraries or dynamic allocation methods such as new/delete ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes -> http://distortos.org/ C++ RTOS + peripheral drivers. If something missing - use hardware registers instead of pseudo hardware abstraction libraries. It is much easier, efficient, energy wise and much quicker.

Comment: So distortos implements the functions required by C++ runtime ? Ie dynamic allocation and implementation of data structure such as map, vector ?

Comment: Yes it does.  Check yourself

Comment: + check the same guy toolchain.